# Write a Regular Expression in Python to match substring

Tags: python, regex

I'm working on a Python project to find into specified strings like:

> < url: '*something*', uid: '*something*', type: '*something*' >

and i need to get the values *something*.
Example:

```
String value = "url: 'abs52fs', uid: '1fg23s4', type: 'fgh54e'"
re.search("url: '(.*)', uid: '(.*)', type: '(.*)'", value)
```

> OUTPUT: >> [abs52fs, 1fg23s4, fgh54e]

I thought to write a regular expression but it returns a `NoneType` Object.
Can you help me?
Regards

Comment: Could you please add full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind 3 separate calls:

```
>>> import re
>>> value = "url: 'abs52fs', uid: '1fg23s4', type: 'fgh54e'"
>>> url = re.search(r"url:\s'(.*?)'", value)
>>> url.group(1)
'abs52fs'
>>> uid = re.search(r"uid:\s'(.*?)'", value)
>>> uid.group(1)
'1fg23s4'
>>> type = re.search(r"type:\s'(.*?)'", value)
>>> type.group(1)
'fgh54e'
```

If you know your data will always follow the pattern **url**, followed by **uid**, followed by **type**, then you can do:

```
>>> tokens = re.search(r"url:\s'(.*?)',\suid:\s'(.*?)',\stype:\s'(.*?)'", value)
>>> url, uid, type = tokens.groups()
>>> url
'abs52fs'
>>> uid
'1fg23s4'
>>> type
'fgh54e'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression works, but it has a problem. It will wrongly accept strings like this:

```
url: 'abs52fs', url: 'abs52fs', uid: '1fg23s4', type: 'fgh54e'
```

(see https://regex101.com/r/sK0vN1/1)

Try something like this (https://regex101.com/r/xN7zR0/1):

```
url: '([^']*)', uid: '([^']*)', type: '([^']*)'
```